# Criar um Array com os números digitados pelo usuário

Tags: javascript, array

Olá, pessoal. Sou iniciante no estudo de JavaScript e me deparei com um problema que talvez seja relativamente simples. A questão é o seguinte: Não consigo fazer com que os números enviados da variável "num" sejam postos dentro do vetor "numeros". Sempre quando digito console.log(numeros) os números digitados surgem no console como "undefined". Meu código está incompleto e não consigo seguir adiante sem antes resolver esse problema.
Obs: Deixei de fora o código em HTML e CSS, mas caso queiram que eu incremente para melhor visualização estarei postando posteriormente.

```
let numeros = []
function adicionar () {
            let num = Number(document.getElementById('cNum').value)
            let respF = document.getElementById('respFinal')
            
            if (Number(num) < 1 || Number(num) > 100) {
                window.alert('Número Inválido')
            } else {
                let respNum = document.getElementById('cText')
                respNum.innerHTML += `${num}\n`
                numeros.push(Number(num).value)

            }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Me parece que o seu único problema é essa linha:
`numeros.push(Number(num).value)`

Você não precisa fazer `Number(X).value`, esse `.value` não é um atributo válido, por isso, retorna `undefined`.

Mas além disso, `num` já é do tipo `number`, então não precisa reconverte-lo.

Bastaria isso:
`numeros.push(num)`

Creio que isso soluciona.

Comment: Funcionou. Muito obrigado.